# How to get value from the dict..?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am doing my homework
but when I tried to use dict to count the numbers, I found that I cannot get exact value from the list...

```
def get_data(openfile):
    totalcount = 0
    digit_count = {d:0 for d in '123456789'}
    for line in openfile:
        line = line.strip()
        if int(line[0]) != 0 and line[0].isdigit():
            first_digit = line[0]
            totalcount += 1
            digit_count[first_digit] += 1
    print(digit_count)
    contents = []
    for data in digit_count:
        contents.append(data)
    print(contents)
```

Then I used print to see what is in the 'digit_count' and 'contents'.

in the digit_count:

> {'5': 89, '3': 203, '7': 79, '8': 77, '1': 500, '9': 69, '2': 304,
>   '6': 70, '4': 140}

in the content:

> ['5', '3', '7', '8', '1', '9', '2', '6', '4']

Is that aviliable to get the count numbers from the digit_count..?
any ideas?
The numbers I want to get such as 89,203,79...

Comment: You're asking how to get `['5', '3', '7', ...]` from the dict `{'5': 89, '3': 203, '7': 79...}` ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking either, but you may want to look into how to properly iterate over a dictionary.

Comment: You should definitely look into using the `Counter` object in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code to:

```
 for data in digit_count:
            contents.append(digit_count[data])
```

Comment: You could just print out the values of digit_count. No reason to create the unnecessary list

Comment: @cricket_007 you are right. I just modify his code slightly.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the values from your dictionary; just use the `.values()` method.

```
vals = digit_count.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
for data in digit_count:
    contents.append(data)
```

You can use:

```
contents = digit_count.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

print key

```
digit_count.keys()
```

print value

```
digit_count.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
  contents = []
  for data in digit_count:
      contents.append(data)
  print(contents)
```

with

```
  contents = dict(digit_count.items())
  print(contents)
```